# Margin problem in Safari - working fine in FF (wordpress)

Tags: safari, margin

I've found a rather interesting mishap here. 
 I have a negative margin on my navigation as I wanted it to sit specifically. All appears fine in FF, but in Safari my content is jumping up to where my nav is, as if my nav does not exist.

I tried playing around with the numbers, when I change it from -77px to -55 the content jumps where it's supposed to be (but obviously my nav does not).

[Here's](http://pastebin.com/bm5SVDfK) a link to my code via pastebin.

Any help is much appreciated! 
Oh, the site is [here](http://dancersbeyondborders.com/)
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You've got a few problems with the layout design of the site that are causing the problem, I think. It is having issues in Chrome as well.

First, your nav isn't contained in its own `div`, which doesn't really fit in with the design pattern you're following. Consider a redesign with the following:

```
div wrapper
    div header
    div nav
    div content
        div column1, etc
    div footer
div wrapper (end)
```

This will give you much more control over the layout, and you'll make changes on the `nav` div instead of the `ul`. Your `clearing` divs aren't completely necessary as you're not `float`ing any elements, but I think you're using them to create white space - either use margins or assign the nav element a height and your original issue should be resolved. I hope this helps.

Comment: Many thanks for the awesomely quick response! Indeed I just put my nav into a proper div (using an old template - lord knows why it's set up that way) and it seems to have solved it, I had to put a height on it for safari but it looks okay.

Thanks again! 
While I'm here - have you any idea why font-face wouldn't be working on my template?

Comment: No problem! Are the font files in the same directory as the CSS file?